# Active Directory Graph Client: Delete an Application using the C# API

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

There is a call below that causes my program to terminate. Please tell me why.

```
        TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        tcs.SetResult(accessToken);
        ActiveDirectoryClient graphClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
            new Uri($"https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}"),
            async () => { return await tcs.Task; });
// this part runs fine and I can see a list of applications being printed
        foreach (var app in graphClient.Applications.ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{app.AppId}, {app.DisplayName}");
        }
// this call causes the program to terminate 
        var matches = await graphClient.Applications
            .Where(app => app.AppId == clientId)
            .ExecuteAsync();
// the execution never gets to this part:
        foreach (IApplication app in matches.CurrentPage.ToList())
        {
            await app.DeleteAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Do you obtain any exception ? Is it because of the async/await ? How to await this call from your main program ?

Comment: Thanks you Thomas! the problem was the not waiting!

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas mentioned in the comments, the problem was not waiting for the async call